# Pandas DataFrame: How to natively get minimum across range of rows and columns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame that looks similar to this but with 10,000 rows and 500 columns.

[image: My Dataframe]

For each row, I would like to find the minimum value between 3 days ago at 15:00 and today at 13:30.

Is there some native numpy way to do this quickly? 
My goal is to be able to get the minimum value for each row by saying something like "what is the minimum value from 3 days ago ago 15:00 to 0 days ago (aka today) 13:30?"

For this particular example the answers for the last two rows would be:

```
2011-01-09 2481.22
2011-01-10 2481.22
```

My current way is this:

```
1. Get the earliest row (only the values after the start time)
2. Get the middle rows 
3. Get the last row (only the values before the end time)
4. Concat (1), (2), and (3)
5. Get the minimum of (4)
```

But this takes a very long time on a large DataFrame

---

The following code will generate a similar DF:

```
import numpy
import pandas
import datetime

numpy.random.seed(0)

random_numbers = (numpy.random.rand(10, 8)*100 + 2000)
columns        = [datetime.time(13,0) , datetime.time(13,30), datetime.time(14,0), datetime.time(14,30) , datetime.time(15,0), datetime.time(15,30) ,datetime.time(16,0), datetime.time(16,30)] 
index          = pandas.date_range('2011/1/1', '2011/1/10')
df             = pandas.DataFrame(data = random_numbers, columns=columns, index = index).astype(int)

print df
```

---

Here is the json version of the dataframe:

'{"13:00:00":{"1293840000000":2085,"1293926400000":2062,"1294012800000":2035,"1294099200000":2086,"1294185600000":2006,"1294272000000":2097,"1294358400000":2078,"1294444800000":2055,"1294531200000":2023,"1294617600000":2024},"13:30:00":{"1293840000000":2045,"1293926400000":2039,"1294012800000":2035,"1294099200000":2045,"1294185600000":2025,"1294272000000":2099,"1294358400000":2028,"1294444800000":2028,"1294531200000":2034,"1294617600000":2010},"14:00:00":{"1293840000000":2095,"1293926400000":2006,"1294012800000":2001,"1294099200000":2032,"1294185600000":2022,"1294272000000":2040,"1294358400000":2024,"1294444800000":2070,"1294531200000":2081,"1294617600000":2095},"14:30:00":{"1293840000000":2057,"1293926400000":2042,"1294012800000":2018,"1294099200000":2023,"1294185600000":2025,"1294272000000":2016,"1294358400000":2066,"1294444800000":2041,"1294531200000":2098,"1294617600000":2023},"15:00:00":{"1293840000000":2082,"1293926400000":2025,"1294012800000":2040,"1294099200000":2061,"1294185600000":2013,"1294272000000":2063,"1294358400000":2024,"1294444800000":2036,"1294531200000":2096,"1294617600000":2068},"15:30:00":{"1293840000000":2090,"1293926400000":2084,"1294012800000":2092,"1294099200000":2003,"1294185600000":2001,"1294272000000":2049,"1294358400000":2066,"1294444800000":2082,"1294531200000":2090,"1294617600000":2005},"16:00:00":{"1293840000000":2081,"1293926400000":2003,"1294012800000":2009,"1294099200000":2001,"1294185600000":2011,"1294272000000":2098,"1294358400000":2051,"1294444800000":2092,"1294531200000":2029,"1294617600000":2073},"16:30:00":{"1293840000000":2015,"1293926400000":2095,"1294012800000":2094,"1294099200000":2042,"1294185600000":2061,"1294272000000":2006,"1294358400000":2042,"1294444800000":2004,"1294531200000":2099,"1294617600000":2088}}'

Comment: Would first doing a ``rolling_min`` to get the minimum for each column for the last 3 rows, and then a `min` to get the minimum in that new rows, result in what you want?

Comment: How did you arrive at `2011-01-10 2481.22`? Could you explain your expected output in a bit more detailed manner?

Comment: Sure. Take the row of 2011-01-10. I want to gather all of the values from 3 days ago (3 rows ago) after 15:00 (2011-01-07 15:30 value, 2011-01-07 2011-01-07 16:00 value, 2011-01-07 16:30 value) until today (2011-01-10) 13:30. So basically each cell between 2011-01-07 15:30 until today 13:30. After I gather these value, I get the minimum value of the bunch.

Comment: In one of your earlier comments to the deleted answer here you said "The exact starting and ending points of the time range will vary". Could you shed more light on that too?

Comment: @joris That wouldn't only because I don't want all the values in the first row to be included, and I don't want all the values in the last row to be included. For example, if I say " I want the minimum value between 2 days ago at 16:00 and 0 days ago (aka today) at 15:30" then I would only use the 16:30 value of the earliest row and all the value up until  15:30 of the latest row.

Comment: Also, in the same comment you said "custom business day could make it messy". Give more details on how custom business days would get involved?

Comment: @Divakar Sure, basically the user will input the starting and ending points, and I have to devise a way to get the minimum values between them. So sometimes I will get the minimum values between 4 days ago 14:00 and 2 days ago at 13:00, other times I will get the minimum values between 2 days ago at 16:00 and 0 days ago (aka today) at 15:30.

Comment: You'll get a lot more answers if you include a copy-pastable starting point for a dataframe.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon do you mean code that generates this dataframe?

Comment: No, more like pasting the result of `df.head().to_json()` so that I can get similar data in my session as quickly as possible.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon I've added the python code to generate this dataframe and also the json version of this dataframe. The columns names are datetime.time types and the index is a pandas.DatetimeIndex type in the original version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can first stack the DataFrame to create a series and then index slice it as required and take the min. For example:

```
first, last = ('2011-01-07', datetime.time(15)), ('2011-01-10', datetime.time(13, 30))
df.stack().loc[first: last].min()
```

The result of `df.stack` is a `Series` with a `MultiIndex` where the inner level is composed of the original columns. We then slice using `tuple` pairs with the start and end date and times. 
If you're going to be doing lots of such operations then you should consider assigning `df.stack()` to some variable. You might then consider changing the index to a proper `DatetimeIndex`. Then you can work with both the time series and the grid format as required.

Here's another method which avoids stacking and is a lot faster on DataFrames of the size you're actually working with (as a one-off; slicing the stacked `DataFrame` is a lot faster once it's stacked so if you're doing many of these operations you should stack and convert the index).
It's less general as it works with `min` and `max` but not with, say, `mean`. It gets the `min` of the subset of the first and last rows and the `min` of the rows in between (if any) and takes the `min` of these three candidates.

```
first_row = df.index.get_loc(first[0])
last_row = df.index.get_loc(last[0])
if first_row == last_row:
    result = df.loc[first[0], first[1]: last[1]].min()
elif first_row < last_row:
    first_row_min = df.loc[first[0], first[1]:].min()
    last_row_min = df.loc[last[0], :last[1]].min()
    middle_min = df.iloc[first_row + 1:last_row].min().min()
    result = min(first_row_min, last_row_min, middle_min)
else: 
    raise ValueError('first row must be <= last row')
```

Note that if `first_row + 1 == last_row` then `middle_min` is `nan` but the result is still correct as long as `middle_min` doesn't come first in the call to `min`.

Answer (score 6):

Take the following example, it is easier to understand.

```
|            | 13:00:00 | 13:30:00 | 14:00:00 | 14:30:00 | 15:00:00 | 15:30:00 | 16:00:00 | 16:30:00 | 
|------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------| 
| 2011-01-01 | 2054     | 2071     | 2060     | 2054     | 2042     | 2064     | 2043     | 2089     | 
| 2011-01-02 | 2096     | 2038     | 2079     | 2052     | 2056     | 2092     | 2007     | 2008     | 
| 2011-01-03 | 2002     | 2083     | 2077     | 2087     | 2097     | 2079     | 2046     | 2078     | 
| 2011-01-04 | 2011     | 2063     | 2014     | 2094     | 2052     | 2041     | 2026     | 2077     | 
| 2011-01-05 | 2045     | 2056     | 2001     | 2061     | 2061     | 2061     | 2094     | 2068     | 
| 2011-01-06 | 2035     | 2043     | 2069     | 2006     | 2066     | 2067     | 2021     | 2012     | 
| 2011-01-07 | 2031     | 2036     | 2057     | 2043     | 2098     | 2010     | 2020     | 2016     | 
| 2011-01-08 | 2065     | 2025     | 2046     | 2024     | 2015     | 2011     | 2065     | 2013     | 
| 2011-01-09 | 2019     | 2036     | 2082     | 2009     | 2083     | 2009     | 2097     | 2046     | 
| 2011-01-10 | 2097     | 2060     | 2073     | 2003     | 2028     | 2012     | 2029     | 2011     |
```

Let say we want to find the min from (2, b) to (6, d) **for each row**.

We can just fill the undesired data of the first and the last row by np.inf.

```
df.loc["2011-01-07", :datetime.time(15, 0)] = np.inf
df.loc["2011-01-10", datetime.time(13, 30):] = np.inf
```

you get

```
|            | 13:00:00 | 13:30:00 | 14:00:00 | 14:30:00 | 15:00:00 | 15:30:00 | 16:00:00 | 16:30:00 | 
|------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------| 
| 2011-01-01 | 2054.0   | 2071.0   | 2060.0   | 2054.0   | 2042.0   | 2064.0   | 2043.0   | 2089.0   | 
| 2011-01-02 | 2096.0   | 2038.0   | 2079.0   | 2052.0   | 2056.0   | 2092.0   | 2007.0   | 2008.0   | 
| 2011-01-03 | 2002.0   | 2083.0   | 2077.0   | 2087.0   | 2097.0   | 2079.0   | 2046.0   | 2078.0   | 
| 2011-01-04 | 2011.0   | 2063.0   | 2014.0   | 2094.0   | 2052.0   | 2041.0   | 2026.0   | 2077.0   | 
| 2011-01-05 | 2045.0   | 2056.0   | 2001.0   | 2061.0   | 2061.0   | 2061.0   | 2094.0   | 2068.0   | 
| 2011-01-06 | 2035.0   | 2043.0   | 2069.0   | 2006.0   | 2066.0   | 2067.0   | 2021.0   | 2012.0   | 
| 2011-01-07 | inf      | inf      | inf      | inf      | inf      | 2010.0   | 2020.0   | 2016.0   | 
| 2011-01-08 | 2065.0   | 2025.0   | 2046.0   | 2024.0   | 2015.0   | 2011.0   | 2065.0   | 2013.0   | 
| 2011-01-09 | 2019.0   | 2036.0   | 2082.0   | 2009.0   | 2083.0   | 2009.0   | 2097.0   | 2046.0   | 
| 2011-01-10 | 2097.0   | inf      | inf      | inf      | inf      | inf      | inf      | inf      |
```

In order to get the result:

```
df.loc["2011-01-07": "2011-01-10", :].idxmin(axis=1)

2011-01-07    15:30:00
2011-01-08    15:30:00
2011-01-09    14:30:00
2011-01-10    13:00:00
Freq: D, dtype: object
```

Comment: Is there a way to do with in a vectorized fashion for each row in the dataframe?

Comment: What do you mean by vectorized fashion? using pandas building functions?

Comment: So I can say say get the minimum value for each row from  3 days ago 15:00 to 0 days ago 11:30

Comment: Your answer will get the me the correct answer for the last row. For the last row, the minimum value between the previous 3 rows and the current row will be the answer you provided. However, I'm looking to perform this operation on each row, so for each row I'm looking to get the minimum value from the previous 3 rows to the current row.

Comment: you mean you want to compute, for each day, the min from 15:00 3 day ago to 11:30 of the day in question? Then i suggest you to use @JoeCondron 's answer with a for loop

Comment: I've tried the for loop solution and it is way too slow

Answer (score 6):

A hacky way, but should be fast, is to concat the shifted DataFrames:

```
In [11]: df.shift(1)
Out[11]:
            13:00:00  13:30:00  14:00:00  14:30:00  15:00:00  15:30:00  16:00:00  16:30:00
2011-01-01       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2011-01-02      2054      2071      2060      2054      2042      2064      2043      2089
2011-01-03      2096      2038      2079      2052      2056      2092      2007      2008
2011-01-04      2002      2083      2077      2087      2097      2079      2046      2078
2011-01-05      2011      2063      2014      2094      2052      2041      2026      2077
2011-01-06      2045      2056      2001      2061      2061      2061      2094      2068
2011-01-07      2035      2043      2069      2006      2066      2067      2021      2012
2011-01-08      2031      2036      2057      2043      2098      2010      2020      2016
2011-01-09      2065      2025      2046      2024      2015      2011      2065      2013
2011-01-10      2019      2036      2082      2009      2083      2009      2097      2046

In [12]: df.shift(2).iloc[:, 4:]
Out[12]:
            15:00:00  15:30:00  16:00:00  16:30:00
2011-01-01       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2011-01-02       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2011-01-03      2042      2064      2043      2089
2011-01-04      2056      2092      2007      2008
2011-01-05      2097      2079      2046      2078
2011-01-06      2052      2041      2026      2077
2011-01-07      2061      2061      2094      2068
2011-01-08      2066      2067      2021      2012
2011-01-09      2098      2010      2020      2016
2011-01-10      2015      2011      2065      2013

In [13]: pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :1], df.shift(1), df.shift(2).iloc[:, 4:]], axis=1)
Out[13]:
            13:00:00  13:00:00  13:30:00  14:00:00  14:30:00  15:00:00  15:30:00  16:00:00  16:30:00  15:00:00  15:30:00  16:00:00  16:30:00
2011-01-01      2054       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2011-01-02      2096      2054      2071      2060      2054      2042      2064      2043      2089       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2011-01-03      2002      2096      2038      2079      2052      2056      2092      2007      2008      2042      2064      2043      2089
2011-01-04      2011      2002      2083      2077      2087      2097      2079      2046      2078      2056      2092      2007      2008
2011-01-05      2045      2011      2063      2014      2094      2052      2041      2026      2077      2097      2079      2046      2078
2011-01-06      2035      2045      2056      2001      2061      2061      2061      2094      2068      2052      2041      2026      2077
2011-01-07      2031      2035      2043      2069      2006      2066      2067      2021      2012      2061      2061      2094      2068
2011-01-08      2065      2031      2036      2057      2043      2098      2010      2020      2016      2066      2067      2021      2012
2011-01-09      2019      2065      2025      2046      2024      2015      2011      2065      2013      2098      2010      2020      2016
2011-01-10      2097      2019      2036      2082      2009      2083      2009      2097      2046      2015      2011      2065      2013
```

and take the minimum across the columns (making sure you discard the columns which are too early or too late on a given day:

```
In [14]: pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :1], df.shift(1), df.shift(2).iloc[:, 4:]], axis=1).min(1)
Out[14]:
2011-01-01    2054
2011-01-02    2042
2011-01-03    2002
2011-01-04    2002
2011-01-05    2011
2011-01-06    2001
2011-01-07    2006
2011-01-08    2010
2011-01-09    2010
2011-01-10    2009
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

You can do this more efficiently, but more noisily, by taking the minimum of each shifted DataFrame before concatting:

```
In [21]: pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :1].min(1),
                    df.shift(1).min(1),
                    df.shift(2).iloc[:, 4:].min(1)],
                   axis=1).min(1)
Out[21]:
2011-01-01    2054
2011-01-02    2042
2011-01-03    2002
2011-01-04    2002
2011-01-05    2011
2011-01-06    2001
2011-01-07    2006
2011-01-08    2010
2011-01-09    2010
2011-01-10    2009
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

*Either will be significantly faster than looping through days.*

Comment: This is the closest to what I want, but I'd like the shifts not to be hardcoded. Sometimes I'd like to take the minimum across 5 rows and sometimes across just 2 rows. Do you know a way to do it like that?

Comment: @user1367204 put it in a function.

Comment: Your suggestion is very similar to the current way I do it and the way that I described as my current solution in the problem description. Do you know of a non-function-making native way to do with with pandas?

Comment: @user1367204 No, and there won't be one with the condition of slicing some columns on the first/last days. You could try something with stacking, and rolling_min, but I'm not convinced it will be faster. Concatting of the minimums (i.e. my last code block) should be significantly faster and easy to wrap in a function - just use a list-comprehension.

Answer (score 5):

I used pandas' stack() method and timeseries object to build the result from the sample data. This approach generalizes well to any arbitrary time range with a few adjustments, and uses pandas built in functionalies to build the result.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
# import df from json
df = pd.read_json('''{"13:00:00":     {"1293840000000":2085,"1293926400000":2062,"1294012800000":2035,"1294099200000":2086,"1294185600000":2006,"1294272000000":2097,"1294358400000":2078,"1294444800000":2055,"1294531200000":2023,"1294617600000":2024},
                      "13:30:00":{"1293840000000":2045,"1293926400000":2039,"1294012800000":2035,"1294099200000":2045,"1294185600000":2025,"1294272000000":2099,"1294358400000":2028,"1294444800000":2028,"1294531200000":2034,"1294617600000":2010},
                      "14:00:00":{"1293840000000":2095,"1293926400000":2006,"1294012800000":2001,"1294099200000":2032,"1294185600000":2022,"1294272000000":2040,"1294358400000":2024,"1294444800000":2070,"1294531200000":2081,"1294617600000":2095},
                      "14:30:00":{"1293840000000":2057,"1293926400000":2042,"1294012800000":2018,"1294099200000":2023,"1294185600000":2025,"1294272000000":2016,"1294358400000":2066,"1294444800000":2041,"1294531200000":2098,"1294617600000":2023},
                      "15:00:00":{"1293840000000":2082,"1293926400000":2025,"1294012800000":2040,"1294099200000":2061,"1294185600000":2013,"1294272000000":2063,"1294358400000":2024,"1294444800000":2036,"1294531200000":2096,"1294617600000":2068},
                      "15:30:00":{"1293840000000":2090,"1293926400000":2084,"1294012800000":2092,"1294099200000":2003,"1294185600000":2001,"1294272000000":2049,"1294358400000":2066,"1294444800000":2082,"1294531200000":2090,"1294617600000":2005},
                      "16:00:00":{"1293840000000":2081,"1293926400000":2003,"1294012800000":2009,"1294099200000":2001,"1294185600000":2011,"1294272000000":2098,"1294358400000":2051,"1294444800000":2092,"1294531200000":2029,"1294617600000":2073},
                      "16:30:00":{"1293840000000":2015,"1293926400000":2095,"1294012800000":2094,"1294099200000":2042,"1294185600000":2061,"1294272000000":2006,"1294358400000":2042,"1294444800000":2004,"1294531200000":2099,"1294617600000":2088}}
                   '''#,convert_axes=False
                    )
date_idx=df.index                    
# stack the data 
stacked = df.stack()
# merge the multindex into a single idx. 
idx_list = stacked.index.tolist()
idx = []
for item in idx_list:
    day = item[0]
    time = item[1]
    idx += [dt.datetime(day.year, day.month, day.day, time.hour, time.minute)]
# make a time series to simplify slicing
timeseries = pd.TimeSeries(stacked.values, index=idx)
# get the results for each date

for i in range(2, len(date_idx)):
    # get the min values for each day in the sample data. 
    start_time='%s 15:00:00'%date_idx[i-2]
    end_time = '%s 13:30:00'%date_idx[i]
    slice_idx =timeseries.index>=start_time 
    slice_idx *= timeseries.index<=end_time
    print "%s %s"%(date_idx[i].date(), timeseries[slice_idx].min())
```

output:

```
2011-01-03 2003
2011-01-04 2001
2011-01-05 2001
2011-01-06 2001
2011-01-07 2001
2011-01-08 2006
2011-01-09 2004
2011-01-10 2004
```